# Spring URL matching case-insensitive does not map when there are numbers in the url

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I was trying to make my URL case-insensitive and got the following code from the net.

However now when my urls are having number it is giving me Status 400 error. It was working fine before this change. Url like localhost\toplevel\234\text\2342 are not recognized now. Can someone please help explaining why this is happening and what need to be changed to make those urls work.

```
     public class CaseInsensitiveAnnotationHandlerMapping  extends AntPathMatcher 
         protected boolean doMatch(String pattern, 
    String path, boolean fullMatch, Map<String, String> uriTemplateVariables) {
     return super.doMatch(pattern.toLowerCase(), 
path.toLowerCase(), fullMatch, uriTemplateVariables);
            }

    }
```

my Servlet-Context.xml

```
    <beans:bean class="com.darproject.webUtils.CaseInsensitiveAnnotationHandlerMapping" /> 
    <beans:bean id="validator" class="org.springframework.validation.beanvalidation.LocalValidatorFactoryBean" />
<beans:bean id="conversion-service" class="org.springframework.format.support.FormattingConversionServiceFactoryBean" />
    <beans:bean name="handlerAdapter" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter">
    <beans:property name="webBindingInitializer">
        <beans:bean class="org.springframework.web.bind.support.ConfigurableWebBindingInitializer">
            <beans:property name="conversionService" ref="conversion-service"></beans:property>
            <beans:property name="validator">
                <beans:bean class="org.springframework.validation.beanvalidation.LocalValidatorFactoryBean">
                    <beans:property name="providerClass" value="org.hibernate.validator.HibernateValidator"></beans:property>
                </beans:bean>
            </beans:property>
        </beans:bean>
    </beans:property>
    <beans:property name="messageConverters">
        <beans:list>
            <beans:ref bean="byteArrayConverter"/>
            <beans:ref bean="jaxbConverter"/>
            <beans:ref bean="jsonConverter"/>
            <beans:bean class="org.springframework.http.converter.StringHttpMessageConverter"></beans:bean>
            <beans:bean class="org.springframework.http.converter.ResourceHttpMessageConverter"></beans:bean>
            <beans:bean class="org.springframework.http.converter.xml.SourceHttpMessageConverter"></beans:bean>
            <beans:bean class="org.springframework.http.converter.xml.XmlAwareFormHttpMessageConverter"></beans:bean>
        </beans:list>
    </beans:property>
</beans:bean>
<beans:bean name="byteArrayConverter" class="org.springframework.http.converter.ByteArrayHttpMessageConverter"></beans:bean>
<beans:bean name="jaxbConverter" class="org.springframework.http.converter.xml.Jaxb2RootElementHttpMessageConverter"></beans:bean>
<beans:bean name="jsonConverter" class="org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter"></beans:bean>
<beans:bean name="caseInsensitivePathMatcher" class="com.darproject.webUtils.CaseInsensitiveAnnotationHandlerMapping"/>
<beans:bean name="handlerMapping" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping">
    <beans:property name="pathMatcher" ref="caseInsensitivePathMatcher"></beans:property>
</beans:bean>
```

Methods that are not working now.

```
@RequestMapping(value="/commentswindow/{defectId}/{release}/{defectsRowID}",method=RequestMethod.POST)
public String addUserComments(
        @PathVariable("defectsRowID") long defectsRowID, 
        @PathVariable("defectId") String defectId,
        @PathVariable("release") String release, 
        @ModelAttribute("addComments") UserCommentsModel cmtModel, 
        BindingResult results, 
        Model model,
        HttpServletRequest request, 
        HttpServletResponse response){
```

Answer (score 1):

The case-insensitive conflicts with path variable mapping. You can change your variable name to all lowercase: defectId --> defectid. It should work.

```
@RequestMapping(value="/commentswindow/{defectid}/{release}/{defectsrowid}",method=RequestMethod.POST)public String addUserComments(
    @PathVariable("defectsrowid") long defectsRowID, 
    @PathVariable("defectid") String defectId,
    @PathVariable("release") String release, 
    @ModelAttribute("addComments") UserCommentsModel cmtModel, 
    BindingResult results, 
    Model model,
    HttpServletRequest request, 
    HttpServletResponse response){
```